# How can I replace text only in certain positions, eg ("THE Beatles" or "Beatles, THE")

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have some data in this format:

> ```
>                    Name Number
> 1           The Beatles    100
> 2   Rolling Stones, The    100
> 3 Puff The Magic Dragon    100
> 4         The Offspring    100
> ```

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
        Name = c("The Beatles", "Rolling Stones, The", "Puff The Magic Dragon",
                 "The Offspring"),
      Number = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L)
)
```

I'd like to remove:

- "The" when it's at the beginning. So "The Beatles" should be "Beatles"
- ", The" when it's at the end. So "Rolling Stones, The" should be "Rolling Stones".

But I would like to leave:

- "Puff The Magic Dragon" should be left alone.

This is what I've tried, but it takes the "The" out of "Puff the Magic Dragon" which is not what I want.

```
library(stringr)
df$Name <- str_replace(string = df$Name, "\\, The", "")
df$Name <- str_replace(string = df$Name, "The", "")
```

Gives this:

> ```
>                 Name Number
> 1            Beatles    100
> 2     Rolling Stones    100
> 3 Puff  Magic Dragon    100
> 4          Offspring    100
> ```

Whereas my desired output is:

> ```
>                 Name Number
> 1            Beatles    100
> 2     Rolling Stones    100
> 3 Puff The Magic Dragon 100
> 4          Offspring    100
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the anchors `^` and `$` to indicate the beginning and end of each string. You can also combine pattern groups with `|` to use only one pattern, and you can use the convenience function `str_remove()` for `str_replace(replacement = "")`. These are *regular expressions* and they provide a very concise method of string manipulation. For more info on anchors, see [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html#anchors).

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Name = c(
    "The Beatles", "Rolling Stones, The", "Puff The Magic Dragon",
    "The Offspring"
  ),
  Number = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L)
)
df %>%
  mutate(Name = str_remove_all(Name, "(^The )|(, The$)"))
#>                    Name Number
#> 1               Beatles    100
#> 2        Rolling Stones    100
#> 3 Puff The Magic Dragon    100
#> 4             Offspring    100
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

OR with `sub`

```
sub("^The |, The$", "", df$Name)

#[1] "Beatles"   "Rolling Stones"  "Puff The Magic Dragon" "Offspring"
```

---

Or with `str_replace`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Name = str_replace(Name, "^The |, The$", ""))

#                   Name Number
#1               Beatles    100
#2        Rolling Stones    100
#3 Puff The Magic Dragon    100
#4             Offspring    100
```